# Program.cs has been cloaked

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I created a new Project in TFS. Later, went into Visual Studio, added the project file / sln (and selected Add To Source Control/Create Folder for Solution). All is well except I accidentally selected a WPF project and meant to add a console application instead. Wups!

Deleted the project via documented method: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3287881-delete-projects

Also, performed an "undo pending changes" and deleted the folder from my work space in Windows Explorer. Refreshed Source Control Explorer / get latest on the root. Now, I re-add as a Console Application with the same name and cannot figure out what this error means.

"Program.cs has been cloaked"

... but for every file in the project. Any suggestions? Yes, I am kinda stuck on using a certain/same name.

Comment: Do you mean that you added the WPF project to the existing solution then deleted it to add console app instead? And have you checked in the changes after deleting the folder from the local workspace? Also please check your workspace settings, make sure no `cloak` items added.

Comment: Na... I added a new "Team Project" thru the online portal. And then, added a solution (and project file) to the local workspace. Seems like if I don't follow this method every time, I run into binding issues or unexpected folder / project / solution structure. Honestly, maybe i'm just really untrusting of TFS. Seem to run into some strange issue like this almost every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the workspace of the team project which you added the solution to, make sure the status is **Active**, not **Cloaked**.  (Click `Workspace` dropdown menu in `Source Control Explorer`, and select `Workspaces...` to open the Manage Workspaces dialog.

If modify the workspace doesn't work, please **create a new workspace** and map to a new local folder. Delete the original workspace, then check that again.

[image]

Comment: YES! This was it. Thank you. Not sure how I didn't notice the status on the left after having been in that screen a dozen times.

Comment: In my case, I accidentally mapped my project folder to another folder in the branch. Some how this is happening.